# How to do an animation backwards when its not hovering anymore?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transitions

I found this animated button at codepen, I changed a little bit and now want to add it to my code.
But I want the animation go backwards when the element is not hovered anymore. At the moment it goes again from top to bottom. But I wanted this:

**Hover:** Top to Bottom

**End of Hover:** Bottom to Top

I thought this is possible with `:after:hover`. But it doesn't worked and I'm not pretty sure if this is the correct way.

```css
.btn {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 24px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0.25s;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
  height: 48px;
}

.btn:not(.btn-disabled):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 1, 1, 1) 0s;
}

.btn:not(.btn-disabled):hover:before {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn:not(.btn-disabled):hover {
  color: #ff0080;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffcc;
}

.btn:not(.btn-disabled):active {
  border-bottom-color: #0040ff;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  color: #ff0080;
}

.btn-primary:before {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span>Small Button</span>
</button>
```

Actually my Code is in Sass but I changed it here for the demonstration.

Comment: Did the code from codepen worked like you wanted it?

Comment: @Patrick Mlr No, it was also not backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent the transition from starting from the top when unhovered, set `top: 0` and `height: 0` on the pseudo element when not hovered, and change the `height` to 100% when hovered. When the height moves from 0 to 100% the direction of the animation would be down, and when it goes from 100% to 0, the direction would be up.

```css
.btn {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 24px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0.25s;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
  height: 48px;
}

.btn:not(.btn-disabled):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 1, 1, 1) 0s;
}

.btn:not(.btn-disabled):hover:before {
  height: 100%;
}

.btn span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn:not(.btn-disabled):hover {
  color: #ff0080;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffcc;
}

.btn:not(.btn-disabled):active {
  border-bottom-color: #0040ff;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  color: #ff0080;
}

.btn-primary:before {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span>Small Button</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `btn:before` and provide

```
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 0;
```